# Why are recently asked questions not always listed in newest but are listed in active?

Tags: support, questions, sorting, caching

Sometimes, when I ask a question, it is not listed under the "Newest" sort on the Questions page (`/questions?sort=newest`), but it *is* listed in the "Active" sort (`/questions?sort=active`).

It happens for a few minutes, and then it also appears in "Newest".

Is this a caching issue?

Comment: caching? is it there now?

Comment: Yes, But it shows after 1 to 2 minutes..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to caching; this is normal.

Answer (score 0):

There is a short delay after which your question should appear under "newest" too.

Comment: I'm actually digging why?

Comment: there seems to be kind of a turnus in which new questions get added - we won't know for sure if we don't know the code